# Date Conversion and Date Comparison in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to compare the current date with two given dates in javascript.I am converting date in YYYY-mm-dd format and then comparing the dates. But I am observing strange thing.
this is my code
Java Script

```
function getyear()
{
    var year=document.getElementById('ddlyear').value;
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm} var today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
    document.getElementById('hdndate').value = today;
    var date1=document.getElementById('hdndate').value;
    alert(date1);

    var date2=new Date("2014-01-01");
    var dd = date2.getDate();
    var mm = date2.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

    var yyyy = date2.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm} var date2 = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;

    alert(date2);
    var date3=new Date("2014-12-31");
    var dd = date3.getDate();
    var mm = date3.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

    var yyyy = date3.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm} var date3 = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;

    alert(date3);

    if(year==1)
    {
        alert("January 2014-December 2014");

        if (date1 > date2 && date1 < date3 ){
         alert('Correct Date')
    }
    else{
        alert('Out Side range !!')
    }
    }
    else if(year==2)
    {
        alert("January 2015-December 2015");

    }
}
```

when i tried to alert date2 and date3 I am not getting the date which i have given
The ouput for date2 and date3 is 2013-12-31 and 2014-12-30. I am not getting why this is coming up.Please help me in this regard. I am new to JS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

See the answer listed here regarding the incorrect parsing of dates according to the ISO standard, as I was unable to mark this as a duplicate.  The reason for you issue is the same.  If you check

```
date.toISOString();
```

You will see that the ISO format of the date is correct, but the Date object will by default show the parsed date under the current Time Zone.

[Stack Overflow Post: javascript-date-parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse)